# Change between two images based on mouse location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I couldn't find example for now.

I want my image located as background-image in div to change with location of a mouse, and if possible, with swiping for mobile.

Two images should appear by default, left 50% of the first image and right 50% of the second.

Then when user mouseover on the image, the one image overlays another one based on the mouse location. For example, when user mouseover on the image, say, 0.3 on horizontal scale of 1, he sees left 30% of first image and 70% of the second one.

This transition should be smooth, to change with almost every pixel if that makes sense.

Comment: What's the reason everyone who voted, downvoted my question? Should I make any changes to this? I couldn't find the solution to my question in google using different keywords so I don't think it's that stupid and may help many others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like this?

```js
$(function(){
  var containerWidth = 190;
  // var intervalFlag = false;
  // var updateIntervalFlag;
  $(".cover").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".image1").css("transition", "initial");
    // updateIntervalFlag = setInterval(() => intervalFlag = true, 25);
  });
  $(".cover").mousemove(function(e){
    // if(intervalFlag){
    //   intervalFlag = false;
      var cursorX = e.clientX - $(this).offset().left;
      var percentage = cursorX/containerWidth * 100;
      $(".image1").css("width", percentage + "%");
    // }
  });
  $(".cover").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".image1").css("transition", "width 0.3s");
    $(".image1").css("width", "50%");
    // clearInterval(updateIntervalFlag);
  }); 
});
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #333;
}

.container{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px -3px black;
}

.image1{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300/0000FF/808080?text=left);
  z-index: 1;
  background-size:cover;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
.image2{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: right;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/300/000000/FFFFFF?text=right);
  background-size:cover;
}
.cover{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <span class="image1"></span>
    <span class="image2"></span>
    <div class="cover"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've also included (as commented lines) the ability to set an interval for calculating the new widths. This could be useful, too.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat hard to understand what you mean with:

> Two images should appear by default, left 50% of the first image and right
>   50% of the second. And when user mouseover on the image, say, 0.3 on x-axis 
>   of 1, he sees left 30% of first image and 70% of the second one.

But I guess you can create a JS function thats suits your need and register it to the respective HTML elments with  onmouseover/onmousedown/... whatever you want to do.

Edit:

Ah, I think I get it now. Use onmousemove, get the mouse position from the event, calculate the new widths of the two images accordingly and set them via DOM access (e.g. `document.getElementById("img1").style.width="30%";`, `document.getElementById("img2").style.width="70%";`).

Comment: Thanks, I tried to explain more clearly. The main issue is smooth transition based on mouse position, I didn't find implementation of this and maybe someone could point me in the right direction.